# Sorted insertion in array of strings

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, memory

I'm working on a program where I require loading dictionary files to memory. I decided to try to implement a sorted insert in order to keep the array of words in alphabetic, unfortunately when I take into consideration the first position of the array I get a segmentation fault and I really have no idea why.

Here is the sorted insert function I'm using

```c
int sorted_insert(char** dic, char *st_w, int wr_c)
{
    /*check if array has space*/
    if(wr_c >= DIC_SIZE)
    {
        perror("ERROR: array has no free space.\n");
        exit(-1);
    }
    
    char *dyn_w = (char*) malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(st_w) + 1);
    strcpy(dyn_w, st_w);

    /*first insert*/
    if (wr_c == 0)
    {
        dic[0] = dyn_w;
        return wr_c + 1;
    }

    /*shift elements to the right until index of insertion is found*/
    size_t i;
    for (i = wr_c - 1; ((i >= 0) && (strcmp(dic[i], dyn_w) > 0)); i--)
        dic[i + 1] = dic[i];

    /*insert string*/
    dic[i + 1] = dyn_w;

    return wr_c + 1;
}

void read_file(char *file_path, char **dictionary ,int *counter)
{
    FILE *f_pointer = fopen(file_path, "r");
    char st_word[MAX_WORD_SIZE];

    if (!f_pointer)
    {
        perror("ERROR: failed to open file read stream.\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    
    while (fscanf(f_pointer, "%[^-\n ] ", st_word) != EOF) 
    {
        (*counter) = sorted_insert(dictionary, st_word, (*counter));
    }

    /*set last element of array to NULL*/
    dictionary[(*counter)] = NULL;

    fclose(f_pointer);
}

int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    char **dic = (char **)malloc(sizeof(char *) * (DIC_SIZE + 1));
    char *dic_dir = "dic/portugues04-04-sl.dict";
    int c_dic = 0;

    read_file(dic_dir, dic, &c_dic);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. It looks like `dic[i + 1] = dic[i];` could cause a buffer overrun. When `i` is `wr_c - 1` then the left hand side will be `dic[wr_c]` which is probably an overflow. But difficult to tell for sure with incomplete code like that. So please provide an MRE. That is provide the `main`, the code that calls this function, the header includes and any other minimal code needed to reproduce the problem.

Comment: To copy a string using `malloc`, you can just call `strdup`, rather than explicitly calling `strlen`, `malloc`, and `strcpy`.

Comment: `size_t i`. That is an unsigned type. So `(i >= 0)` is always true (your compiler may have had a warning about that). So when `i` is decremented past 0 the index will be a large value causing an invalid array index access. Also your code relies on `i` being -1 if the entry needs to be inserted at the first element. Try changing `i` to be a signed type.

Comment: @kaylum that was the problem, thanks for the help.